# Updating object with null field in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm working with Spring App, so to work with DB I use Spring Data JPA. Firstly I saved an object. And after some time I need to update this object in the table. But at this moment my object contains one field which is null. But I don't want to update this field with null. So my question is how to prevent updating fields with null? Maybe there is an annotation or some property to solve my problem.My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "user_name")
@Field
private String username;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "user_identity")
private String identity;

@Column(name="user_image")
private String image;

@Column(name="user_joined")
private String date;

@Column(name="user_origin")
private String origin;

@Column(name="user_sub")
private String sub;
```

I save and update this entity with implementation of JpaRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>
```

it looks like this:

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

....
userRepository.save(user);
```

I've saved my object with not null sub-field. And now I want to update some fields of saved entity, but not sub field, which is null in current object. I wonder if there is any possibility to avoid changing user_sub field to null?

Comment: Show your entity and the code that updates it...

Comment: @Cepr0 I've added my code

Comment: to update entity: 1) get it from db: `entity = repo.getOne(id)`; 2) update it fileds: `entity.setField(value)`; 3) save back to db: `repo.save(entity)`

Comment: @Andrey-2310, would you please check my answer? Hope it will help

Comment: @sunkuet02 Unfortunately it didn't. I've already found the solution: 
 Query annotation. But thanks for your try

Answer (score 2):

You can add `@DynamicUpdate` annotation to your `User` class. This will ignore the fields whose values are null. You can simply do like:

```
//other annotations
@DynamicUpdate
public class User {
    // other codes inside class
}
```

You can follow a good example from [Mkyong's site](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamic-update-attribute-example/).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, guys. I found the solution: @Query will help to update fields that I need

Comment: Without `@Query` you can do this by adding `@DynamicUpdate` to your entity class. No needs to check whether the field is null or not